# web scraping with selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a python script to web scrape a betting site for up coming games with selenium. I keep getting this long error.

Here's the code.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

os.environ['PATH'] += r"C:/Users/dub6m/OneDrive/Documents/chromedriver_win32"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.888sport.com/tennis/')
athlete1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'featured-matches-widget__event-text featured-matches-widget__event-competitor')
print(athlete1.text)
```

This was meant to print the first athlete in a tennis match.

It threw this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dub6m\OneDrive\Desktop\betbot\888sports.py", line 8, in <module>
    element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'featured-matches-widget__event-text featured-matches-widget__event-competitor')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dub6m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 831, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dub6m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\dub6m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".featured-matches-widget__event-text featured-matches-widget__event-competitor"}
  (Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.50)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0070DCE3+50899]
    (No symbol) [0x0069E111]
    (No symbol) [0x005A5588]
    (No symbol) [0x005D08F9]
    (No symbol) [0x005D0AFB]
    (No symbol) [0x005FF902]
    (No symbol) [0x005EB944]
    (No symbol) [0x005FE01C]
    (No symbol) [0x005EB6F6]
    (No symbol) [0x005C7708]
    (No symbol) [0x005C886D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00973EAE+2566302]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x009A92B1+2784417]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x009A327C+2759788]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x007A5740+672048]
    (No symbol) [0x006A8872]
    (No symbol) [0x006A41C8]
    (No symbol) [0x006A42AB]
    (No symbol) [0x006971B7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77007BA9+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77A7BB3B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x77A7BABF+191]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `By.CLASS_NAME` expects a single class name and you've passed it two, 'featured-matches-widget__event-text' and 'featured-matches-widget__event-competitor'. Turn it into a CSS selector

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.featured-matches-widget__event-text.featured-matches-widget__event-competitor')
```

where a `.` means a class name.

You should also add a wait to make sure the page is fully loaded before beginning to scrape the page.

NOTE: As of Selenium 4.6+, you no longer need to specify the path to ChromeDriver. It now has [DriverManager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) which will download, setup, and generally take care of drivers for you.

The full working code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.888sport.com/tennis/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
athlete1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.featured-matches-widget__event-text.featured-matches-widget__event-competitor')))
print(athlete1.text)
```

and it prints

```
Purcell, M
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this way:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.888sport.com/tennis/')
athlete1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'featured-matches-widget__event-competitor')
print(athlete1.text)
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Purcell, M
```

Comment: Throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use XPath and loop through players:

```
players = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH , "//a[@class='event-description event-description--inplay']")
for player in players:
    print(player.text)
```